# Can initial focus be set to search field in WordPress Media Library?

Tags: wordpress, media, administration, wp-admin

I was just wondering if it's possible somehow (via an addon maybe?) to set the initial focus when the WordPress media library pops up to be the search field?

I have a lot of posts where I need to select images very fast and need to type in the names of the images to find them and this would be exceptionally handy except I've looked on Wordpress.org and a few other places that I know of and can't find a plugin that can do this although someone here might know of one or perhaps a way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance,

Best wishes,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a fantastic solution to this a very helpful person showed me how over on Stack Exchange :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265740/can-initial-focus-be-set-to-search-field-in-wordpress-media-library

Sorry if posting here in Stack Overflow was the wrong place as I came across the Stack Exchange site after I'd posted this. Not really sure what the difference between the two places is though?

Best wishes,

Mark